# Can't connect through socket after changing data directory

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-12.10

When trying to start mysql I get the error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

This problem emerged while I was trying to relocate my mysql data directory following [this guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-data-default-directory.html) . As described there, I changed the location in the mysql config and updated the AppArmor config.

The location mentioned in the error message doesn't exist/is empty, although I didn't change anything in the socket configuration for mysql.

This problem also causes the mysql service to fail starting.

Thanks in advance,
Rickyfox

Comment: did you grant permissions to mysql to read/write in new folder?

Comment: guess so, new data directory is in my home directory with normal user permissions. Should work, right?

Comment: no. You need to grant permissions to mysql user, not to your os user. Please check the permission using `ls -l /path/to/files/`. Also you can switch off apparmor to make sure that problem in mysql and not in this application.